# How do I delete the last character in each line using vim

Tags: vim, editor

I have a file:

```
12345a
123456b
1234567c
12345678d
123456789e
```

How do I delete the last character in each line.
And the file will be

```
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You could use `:%s/.\{1}$//` to delete 1 character off the end of each line.

Comment: You don't need the `{1}` − just `:%s/.$//` will work fine ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, What is the meaning of `.` here?

Comment: @SangminKim, According to Vim's documentation, `.` matches any character. See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html

Answer (score 42):

`:%normal $x`

- `:` puts you into command line mode
- `%` is a range representing the entire file
- `normal` says we're running a normal mode command
- `$x` deletes the last character in the line

Some overlap with other answers, but to me this one reads most simply.

Comment: This use of `%norm` or `%normal` is very useful. You can also append every line with `%norm A` and prepend with `%norm I` adding in the characters you wish to add.

Comment: how do I delete the last two chars ?

Comment: @Ted `:%normal $x$x`

Comment: @Ted @tjstankus 

`:%norm $xx`

achieves the same thing with fewer characters (2x's for the last 2 characters)

Answer (score 14):

**TLDR:** `:%s/.$//`

*For explanation and more examples read on.*

- `:%s/.$//`

  - deletes any character at the end of all lines (or better to say: replaces any character at the end with nothing)
  - `s` = *[substitute](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace)* command
  - `.` = any character
  - if you want to delete `.` (not any character) use `\.$` instead of `.$`
- `:'<,'>s/.$//g`

  - deletes any character at the end of all lines **of the current selection**
  - `'<,'>` = current selection (you get this by `SHIFT+V`, then selecting the lines, then `:`)
- `:%s/;$//`

  - deletes `;` at the end of all line
  - useful if you copy & paste code from a language that needs `;` to one that doesn't

Answer (score 10):

Use `:g` command:

```
:g/^/norm $x
```

- `^` matches every line which will be operated on.
- `norm` is shorthand for `normal`, going before the normal command you want to execute.
- `$x` move to the end of a line, and delete a character in normal mode